# Open realm with new realmconfiguration

Tags: android, realm

I used Realm in my android untill now with
 `new RealmConfiguration.Builder(this)  .build();`

I just read later about the possibility to add schema and migration. 
So in my new version for my app i want to add the migration feature.
so i changed the line above to:

```
new RealmConfiguration.Builder(this) .schemaVersion(0) .migration(new Migration()) .build();
```

but now I get the error

```
IllegalArgumentException: Configurations cannot be different if used to open the same file.
```

How can i change the configuration without deleting the database

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I think your problem is that you are creating your RealmConfiguration multiple times. That shouldn't be a problem by itself (although it is inefficient), but the problem arises with your `Migration` class. Internally we compare all state in the configuration objects and if you didn't override `equals` and `hashCode` in your `Migration` class you have a case where `new Migration().equals(new Migration()) == false` which will give you the error you are seeing.

One solution is adding this:

```
public class Migration implements RealmMigration {

  // Migration logic...

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return 37;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    return (o instanceof Migration);
  }
}
```

Comment: This solved my Problem. Took me a while to understand that it was my actually my problem. I now limit the creation of RealmConfiguration as you recommended. but I have to use it more then once because I use realm in multiple threads.

Comment: Saving it in a static variable in your application class or save it as a the Default configuration should both work as ways of having easy access to it.

Comment: In Java `new Migration() != new Migration()` unless you override equals/hashcode. If you continuously create configuration objects, you also keep recreating migration objects. By overriding equals/hashcode you tell Java that it is the same object no matter if it was created twice.

Comment: @ChristianMelchior Can u please explain me, why 37 ?

Comment: That was just chosen at random, it could be any number

Comment: My issue was that I was recreating `RealmConfiguration` and `compactOnLaunch` was recreating `DefaultCompactOnLaunchCallback` internally.

Comment: Then why not chose 42, if it's a random number

Answer (score 0):

When you set a new schema version with `schemaVersion()`, the version number should equal to or higher than the schema version of the existing realm file. The `RealmMigration()` you provide should then be able to convert older version of schemas to the new version.

I'd suggest to check your existing schema version first, then check your `RealmObject`s for appropreate conversion.

Comment: The problem seems to be that when i created the realm the first time i didn't add schema at all. See my post on how i created it.